# Problems with the transfer of custom class in WCF c#

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, service

I am transferring data between a server and a client. The client easily receives the usual data types such as `int` from the server, but if you pass a custom class to it, then I get the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while getting the HTTP response to http://127.0.0.1:8000/Service. This is probably caused by the fact that the service endpoint binding does not use the HTTP protocol. This may also be caused by the fact that the HTTP request context has been interrupted by the server (possibly due to the service being disabled). See the server logs for details.

I tried many solutions to solve such problems, but nothing helped.
I added getters and setters to class fields, changed `DataContract`, etc to `Serializable`:

Custom Class

```
    namespace c_CardStrategy
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Card
    {
        #region ПОЛЯ
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Effect { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string EffText { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Конструктор
        public Card(int id, string name, string effect, int price, string efftext)
        {
            Price = price;
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            Effect = effect;
            EffText = efftext;
        }
        public Card()
        {
            Name = "";
            Effect = "";
            ID = 0;
            Price = 0;
            EffText = "";
        }
        #endregion
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Moster_Card : Card
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int? Health { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? Power { get; set; }

        public Moster_Card(int id, string name, int? health, int? power, string effect, int price, string efftext) : base(id, name, effect, price, efftext)
        {
            Health = health;
            Power = power;
        }
        public Moster_Card()
        {
            Name = "";
            Effect = "";
            ID = 0;
            Price = 0;
            EffText = "";
            Health = 0;
            Power = 0;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Spell_Card : Card
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int? Charge { get; set; }

        public Spell_Card(int id, string name, string effect, int price, string efftext, int? charge) : base(id, name, effect, price, efftext)
        {
            Charge = charge;
        }
        public Spell_Card()
        {
            Name = "";
            Effect = "";
            ID = 0;
            Price = 0;
            EffText = "";
            Charge = 0;
        }
    }


}
```

Interface

```
    [ServiceContract]
        public interface IGame
        {
            [OperationContract]
            Players GetPlayer(int grid);

            [OperationContract]
            List<Players> Players();

            [OperationContract]
            int GetTurn(int GameGrid);

            [OperationContract]
            void FindGame(Players Player);

            [OperationContract]
            object GetAllCards();

            [OperationContract]
            List<Card> GetDeckOnCode(string code_deck);

            [OperationContract]
            bool Checkuser(string login, string pass);

            [OperationContract]
            void WriteInLog(string Text);
        }
```

Server

```
    namespace c_CardStrategy
    {
        [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
        public class GameServer : IGame
        {
            private List<Players> listPlayers;
            private List<Game> Games;
            public hpartner_cgEntities context;
            ...
            public object GetAllCards()
            {
                context = new hpartner_cgEntities();
                List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();
                foreach(var Card in context.Cards)
                {
                    int id = Card.Card_id;
                    string name = Card.Card_name;
                    int f = Card.Card_eff_id;
                    string eff;
                    switch (f)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            eff = "None";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            eff = "Taunt";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            eff = "Charge";
                            break;
                        default:
                            eff = "None";
                            break;
                    }
                    int price = Card.Card_price;
                    string efftext = Card.Card_eff_text;
                    int? Health = Card.Card_health;
                    int? Power = Card.Card_power;
                    int? Charge = Card.Charge;
                    if (Health != null)
                    {
                        Cards.Add(new Spell_Card(id, name, eff, price, efftext, Charge));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Cards.Add(new Moster_Card(id, name, Health, Power, eff, price, efftext));
                    }
                }
                return Cards;
            }
            ...
    }
    }
```

Client

```
    public partial class DecksWindow : Window
        {
            private GameClient Client;
            public DecksWindow(GameClient client)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Client = client;
            }

            private void New_deck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Deck_list.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();
                try
                {
                    Cards = Client.GetAllCards() as List<Card>;
                    foreach (Card Card in Cards)
                    {
                        StackPanel Sp = new StackPanel();
                        Sp.Height = 170;
                        Sp.Width = 150;
                        Sp.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 5, 0);
                        Sp.Background = Brushes.Red;
                        Sp.Tag = Card.IDk__BackingField.ToString();
                        Sp.Uid = 2.ToString();
                        Deck_list.Children.Add(Sp);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tb.Text += ex.Message;
                }
                //tb.Text = Client.Checkuser("Admin", "Admin").ToString();

            }
        }
```

config Client

```
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
      </startup>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="hpartner_cgEntities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=hpartnerlink.ru;user id=hpartner;password=M7gn46Wx3b;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=hpartner_cg&quot;" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="262144"  executionTimeout="103600"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGame" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGame1" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGame" contract="GameServiceReference.IGame"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IGame" />
          <endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:8000/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGame1" contract="ServiceReference1.IGame"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IGame1" />
        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Config Server

```
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
      </startup>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="hpartner_cgEntities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=hpartnerlink.ru;user id=hpartner;password=M7gn46Wx3b;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=hpartner_cg&quot;" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="debug">
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="MyServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="debug" />
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You `Card` class MUST be a `DataContract` so you can see the `class` on the client side. Each properties need `DataMember` attribute too. Note that i have never had the use of derived class in a `WCF` service so i am not sure if a derived class also need the `DataContract` or not but i believe it should as well have it.

Comment: @Franck, So already did, but did not help
`[DataContract]
    public class Card
    {
        #region ПОЛЯ
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Effect { get; set; }
        ...
        `

Comment: i know it doesn't help your error. But your code will need that to work on the client side since you have return type of that object. It wont work if the class is not a `DataContract` with `DataMember`. Your error is a communication error that has to do with your bindings. You need to add your `web.config` to the post so someone can help.

Comment: @Franck, Updated the topic, added configs. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I doubt your server is using the basicHttpBinding which your client is using.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the WSDL of the web service after you host the service?
I doubt that the configuration may be too simple. I suggest you apply the below configuration on the server side.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="YourNamespace.GameServer " behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="YourNamespace.IGame " ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Service/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

After we host the service, thereby we could access the service information by typing the service address in the browser address bar.

```
http://localhost:8000/service
```

Besides, we may need administrative privilege when hosting the service.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.